# Busemann functions and inequalities

Tags: analytic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Let $D$ is the hyperbolic unit disk. Let $\alpha,\,\beta\in S^1$, where $S^1$ is the boundary of $D$. Let $w\in D$. I know that Busemann function for hyperbolic disk is
$$B(w,\alpha)=\ln\frac{1-|w|^2}{|\alpha-w|^2}.$$
I know that there is the following inequality,
$$|B(w,\alpha)-B(v,\alpha)|\leq L(w,v),$$
where $L(w,v)$ is the geodesic length between points $w$ and $v$.
Is it possible to write down something similar for different bounday points, i.e. $|B(w,\alpha)-B(w,\beta)|\vee L(\alpha,\beta)$, where $\vee$ is comparison sign?

Comment: What is $L(\alpha,\beta)$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan , I've clarified this point

Comment: No, you did not clarify: I asked about $L(\alpha, \beta)$ (which I do not understand) and you answered for $L(v,w)$ (which I did understand).

Comment: @MoisheKohan naively I assume something like 'regularized' version. For instance, if I set $z_1=e^{\epsilon}e^{i\alpha}$ and $z_2=e^{\epsilon}e^{i\beta}$, I naively assume that I can 'capture' divergence as $1/\epsilon$

Comment: Whatever you "assume," you should spell out what this is. (and not in a comment but in the question itself), otherwise, your question is meaningless. Note that if your quantity is finite, it will not be $PSL(2,R)$-invariant.